# After the login click i am not able to render the data that i got from Login form into the HomePage

Tags: reactjs

After the login click i am not able to render the data that i got from Login form into the HomePage as i want to see the username and password into the HomePage after i entered the username and password that has already been in my local storage(at present this is not done as i am just checking the login with the dummy data).

```
App Component:
  
  import LoginForm from "./Component/LoginForm/LoginForm";
  import HomePage from "./Component/HomePage/HomePage";
  import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    function App() {
      const user = [{ username: "admin" }, { password: "admin" }];
      const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

      useEffect(() => {
        const isUserLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedInn");
        if (isUserLoggedIn === "1") {
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        }
      }, []);

      const loginHandler = () => {
        localStorage.setItem("isLoggedInn", "1");
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        // return [username,password];
      };
      const logoutHandler = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedInn");
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      };
      const onSaveDataHandler = (newData) =>{
        console.log(newData);
        console.log('inside app');
      }
      const dataFormHandler = (username,password) => {
        return username;
      }

      return (
        <div>
          {!isLoggedIn && <LoginForm adminUser={user} onLogin={loginHandler} onSaveData={onSaveDataHandler} dataForm={dataFormHandler}/>}
          {isLoggedIn && <HomePage onLogout={logoutHandler} user={dataFormHandler[0]}/>}
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;

LoginForm Component:

import styles from "./LoginForm.module.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import SignUp from "../SignUp/SignUp";
const LoginForm = (props) => {
  const [enteredUsername, setEnteredUsername] = useState("");
  const [enteredPassword, setEnteredPassword] = useState("");
  const [isTrue, setTrue] = useState(true);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  const onChangeHandlerUsername = (event) => {
    setEnteredUsername(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value === enteredUsername) {
      setTrue(true);
    }
  };
  const onChangeHandlerPassword = (event) => {
    setEnteredPassword(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value === enteredPassword) {
      setTrue(true);
    }
  };
  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (
      enteredUsername === props.adminUser[0].username &&
      enteredPassword === props.adminUser[1].password
    ) {
      props.onLogin();
      props.dataForm(enteredUsername,enteredPassword);
    } else {
      setTrue(false);
    }
  };
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setIsClicked(true);
  };
  const sendDataToChild = (entereduserData) =>{
    const userData = {
      ...entereduserData,
      id: Math.random().toString()
    };
    props.onSaveData(userData);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {isClicked &&
      enteredUsername !== props.adminUser[0].username &&
      enteredPassword !== props.adminUser[1].password ? (
        <SignUp name={enteredUsername} dataTransfer={sendDataToChild}/>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
          <h1 className={styles.blink_me}>W E L C O M E</h1>
          <div className={`${styles.box} ${!isTrue && styles.wrong}`}>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={enteredUsername}
              placeholder="Enter Username"
              className={styles.email}
              onChange={onChangeHandlerUsername}
            ></input>
            <input
              type="password"
              value={enteredPassword}
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              className={styles.email}
              onChange={onChangeHandlerPassword}
            ></input>
            <div>
              <button className={styles.btn}>Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={onClickHandler}
                type="button"
                className={styles.btn2}
              >
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#top">Forget Password</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default LoginForm;

HomePage Component:

import styler from './HomePage.module.css';

const HomePage = (props) =>{
    return(
        <div className={styler.body}>
        <h2>Login Successfull !</h2>
        <p>Name: {props.user}</p>
        <p>Password: {props.pass}</p>
        <button type='submit' onClick={props.onLogout} className={styler.button}>Logout</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some points which I would like to highlight in the code.

- **dataFormHandler** function: when this function is getting called from the LoginForm component, the output is not getting stored anywhere. See the below code snippet from the LoginForm component.

  ```
   props.dataForm(enteredUsername,enteredPassword)
  ```

You need to store the username and password somewhere. For this you can directly utilize the **onLogin()** method of the LoginForm component and pass in the enteredUsername and enteredPassword as the arguments like below:

```
props.onLogin(enteredUsername, enteredPassword);
```

and then store them somewhere from the App component.

```
const loginHandler = (username, password) => {
   localStorage.setItem("isLoggedInn", "1");
   setIsLoggedIn(true);
   localStorage.setItem("currentUsername", username);
   localStorage.setItem("currentPassword", password);
   // return [username,password];
};
```

- Your dataFormHandler function returns just the username. That doesn't make sense to me. You can instead return an array of 2 elements, username and the password.

  ```
   const dataFormHandler = () => {
   return [
     localStorage.getItem("currentUsername"),
     localStorage.getItem("currentPassword")
   ];
  };
  ```

Now to access these values in the HomePage component, you just need to access them as *props.user[0]* and *props.user[1]*

The code for all the three components can be found below: (ps- I have changed some file paths and removed the classNames and styles just to make it work on my machine)

App Component:

```js
import LoginForm from "./components/LoginForm";
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
  const user = [{ username: "admin" }, { password: "admin" }];
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isUserLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedInn");
    if (isUserLoggedIn === "1") {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    }
  }, []);

  const loginHandler = (username, password) => {
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedInn", "1");
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    localStorage.setItem("currentUsername", username);
    localStorage.setItem("currentPassword", password);
    // return [username,password];
  };
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedInn");
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  };
  const onSaveDataHandler = (newData) => {
    console.log(newData);
    console.log("inside app");
  };
  const dataFormHandler = () => {
    return [
      localStorage.getItem("currentUsername"),
      localStorage.getItem("currentPassword")
    ];
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {!isLoggedIn && (
        <LoginForm
          adminUser={user}
          onLogin={loginHandler}
          onSaveData={onSaveDataHandler}
          dataForm={dataFormHandler}
        />
      )}
      {isLoggedIn && (
        <HomePage onLogout={logoutHandler} user={dataFormHandler()} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

LoginForm Component:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
const LoginForm = (props) => {
  const [enteredUsername, setEnteredUsername] = useState("");
  const [enteredPassword, setEnteredPassword] = useState("");
  const [isTrue, setTrue] = useState(true);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  const onChangeHandlerUsername = (event) => {
    setEnteredUsername(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value === enteredUsername) {
      setTrue(true);
    }
    console.log(enteredUsername);
  };
  const onChangeHandlerPassword = (event) => {
    setEnteredPassword(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value === enteredPassword) {
      setTrue(true);
    }
    console.log(enteredPassword);
  };
  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (
      enteredUsername === props.adminUser[0].username &&
      enteredPassword === props.adminUser[1].password
    ) {
      props.onLogin(enteredUsername, enteredPassword);
      // props.dataForm(enteredUsername, enteredPassword);
    } else {
      setTrue(false);
    }
  };
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setIsClicked(true);
  };
  const sendDataToChild = (entereduserData) => {
    const userData = {
      ...entereduserData,
      id: Math.random().toString()
    };
    props.onSaveData(userData);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {isClicked &&
      enteredUsername !== props.adminUser[0].username &&
      enteredPassword !== props.adminUser[1].password ? (
        <SignUp name={enteredUsername} dataTransfer={sendDataToChild} />
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
          <h1>W E L C O M E</h1>
          <div>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={enteredUsername}
              placeholder="Enter Username"
              onChange={onChangeHandlerUsername}
            ></input>
            <input
              type="password"
              value={enteredPassword}
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              onChange={onChangeHandlerPassword}
            ></input>
            <div>
              <button>Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button onClick={onClickHandler} type="button">
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#top">Forget Password</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default LoginForm;
```

HomePage Component:

```js
const HomePage = (props) => {
  const name = props.user[0];
  const pass = props.user[1];
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login Successfull !</h2>
      <p>Name: {name}</p>
      <p>Password: {pass}</p>
      <button type="submit" onClick={props.onLogout}>
        Logout
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `HomePage` `user` prop is invalid, as you pass a function there (and what's more wrong, you try to get this function's 0th element, as it were an array).

What you should do instead is store the username somewhere (accessible from within your `App` component), and pass it directly as the `HomePage` prop.

To give you an idea, your `dataFormHandler` only returns the first of its two arguments, so in my opinion it's pointless. Your scenario'd work under such conditions:

```
const myusername = 'mock username';
const mypassword = 'mock password';

return <HomePage onLogout={logoutHandler} user={dataFormHandler(myusername, mypassword)}/>
```

**edit**
You jave to modify your `loginHandler(username, password)`, inside it: set the values as state, then do what I wrote earlier.

Comment: I am trying this can u do the corrections in the code.                                                                                                                                 const dataFormHandler = (username,password) => {
      return [username,password];
    }
    // const myUsername = dataFormHandler();
    // const myPassword = dataFormHandler();
    return (
        {isLoggedIn && <HomePage onLogout={logoutHandler} user={myUsername} pass={myPassword}/>}

Comment: LoginForm and HomePage are child and App is Parent so i am first passing the data from child to parent and than from parent to other child.